# How to force error or 'NULL' when accessing a list element that doesn't exist?

Tags: r

I find odd this is even possible:

```
> x <- list(abc = 2, def = 4)
> x$a
[1] 2
```

Ideally, I would like to force the error if someone is trying to access a list element and the element doesn't exist.  I would even be fine if the result is NULL.  But apparently R is trying to be too smart and find another field that resembles the invoked attribute.

I tried looking at `options`, but seems there is no option to change the list access behavior.

Thanks in advance.

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.3                         
year           2015                        
month          12                          
day            10                          
svn rev        69752                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
nickname       Wooden Christmas-Tree
```

I know, it's an old R version.  Our models are in production and there seems to be no intention to upgrade Prod R version any time soon.

---

**UPDATE:**
Found a way to turn partial matching into a warning:

```
> options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)
> x$a
[1] 2
Warning message:
In x$a : partial match of 'a' to 'abc'
```

Comment: use square brackets : `x[["a"]]`

Comment: We would have to update a bunch of code, but that would be an option.

Comment: I think `$` will use partial matching, so using `[[.]]` seems a (the?) way to go - more at `?`$`` i guess

Comment: Seems like it.  Syntax-wise, I'd prefer the dollar sign.  Sometimes we have lists of many levels and it can get ugly[er] pretty quickly.

Comment: In that situation I kind of fall the other way; I find it easier / safer / doable passing names / indices etc through nested lists using the brackets

Comment: I guess I'd have to go that route.  Seems there is no plan to add option to disable partial matching anyways: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2004-February/028962.html

Comment: re you edit: nice find - it might be worth adding it as an answer. You can then escalate that to an error with `options(warn=2)`

Comment: Right. Or use options(warning.expression = some_function), where some_function acts on specific warnings, including raising an error.

Comment: @user20650 Feel free to post an answer.  Otherwise, I'll answer it tomorrow.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify to return an error with argument `warn=2` in `options` when there's a partial match of variable name

```
options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE, warn = 2)
```